# Attribute Error Help For Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a paint clone using pygame, but I'm stuck at fixing this error. I'm very new at python so please don't judge my horrible code XD The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\aggao\Desktop\Paint Project.py", line 32, in <module>
    draw.rect(screen,(0,255,0),pencilRect,2) 
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'rect'
```

.

```
from pygame import *
from random import *
from math import *
screen = display.set_mode((1280,720))
display.set_caption("Paint Program")
running = True
#graphics -------------------------------------------------
bg=image.load("background.jpg").convert_alpha()
logo=image.load("logo.png").convert_alpha()
draw=image.load("draw.png").convert_alpha()
fill=image.load("fill.png").convert_alpha()
text=image.load("txt.png").convert_alpha()
drawC=image.load("cir.png").convert_alpha()
drawR=image.load("rect.png").convert_alpha()
erase=image.load("eraser.png").convert_alpha()

bg=transform.scale(bg,(1280,720))

screen.blit(bg,(0,0))
screen.blit(logo,(0,0))
screen.blit(draw,(10,150))
screen.blit(fill,(210,150))
screen.blit(drawC,(10,300))
screen.blit(drawR,(210,300))
screen.blit(erase,(10,450))
screen.blit(text,(210,450))


hitD=Rect(10,150,150,150)

pencilRect = Rect(20,80,40,40)
draw.rect(screen,(0,255,0),pencilRect,2)
#gameloop -------------------------------------------------
while running:
    for evnt in event.get():
        if evnt.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    mx, my = mouse.get_pos()
    mb = mouse.get_pressed()

#Paint Brush -------------------------------------------------
    if hitD.collidepoint(mx,my) and mb[0]==1:
        print("I CHOOSE PAINTBRUSH!")


    display.flip()
quit()
```

Comment: You have problem because you use `from pygame import *`. If you use `import pygame` then you have to call `pygame.draw.rect()` and you will have no conflict with variable `draw = image.load(...)`

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing variable and function names. You can't name a variable `draw`, as it will mess with the inbuilt `pygame.draw...()`function, as you have chosen to import everything from pygame via`from pygame import *`, see bottom of this answer.

When you do:

```
draw=image.load("draw.png").convert_alpha()
```

and then: when you then call:

```
pencilRect = Rect(20,80,40,40)
draw.rect(screen,(0,255,0),pencilRect,2)
```

It thinks you are referring to draw as the image object which you imported on your `image.load` line, and not the in built `pygame.draw.rect()` function. If you write:

```
any_other_name=image.load("draw.png").convert_alpha()
```

Your code should work. In general practice, try not to mix variable and in-built function names, i.e. don't use function names as variables (things like `list` `len` and in your case: `draw`)

Further to this: you write `from pygame import *`. This means that the `Pygame.draw.rect()` function can be called just by writing `draw.rect()` If you instead do `import pygame as pg` and write `pg.draw.rect()` you will be able to avoid situations like this, and also keep better track of what functions you are using.